# broken command line while using tinker in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

what is the cause of the error?

following my error messages :

```
ErrorException with message 'streamselect(): unable to select [4]: Interrupted system call (maxfd=9)'

[root@localhost ]# E
Exit: Ctrl+D
PHP Notice: fwrite(): send of 1270 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in /laravel_path/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/ExecutionLoop/ForkingLoop.php on line 83
```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cant-use-artisan-tinker-psy-shell-broken could possibly help

Comment: thank you for your answer to my question. but according to the example, he uninstalled Zend Zray. however, dose not exist the file and folder in my server.